# Basic Syntax for passing a Scanner object as a Parameter in a Function

Tags: java, function, parameters, arguments, java.util.scanner

Here is what I wrote which is pretty basic :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Projet {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @param Scanner 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter a digit");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        getChoice(Scanner);
        in.close();
    }

    public static int getChoice(Scanner n){
        n = in.nextInt();
        return n;
    }
}
```

What seems to be wrong here ? I had it working earlier, I had to pass the **Scanner type** and **argument name** as a parameter to the function... and simply call that function in the main using **Scanner type and argument** as an argument to the function ?

**-----EDIT-----**

New Code below for below that will need it :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Projet {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @param Scanner 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter a digit");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(getChoice(in));
        in.close();
    }

    public static int getChoice(Scanner in){
        return in.nextInt();
    }
}
```

@rgettman Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the actual variable name `in` when you call the method, not the class name `Scanner`.

```
getChoice(in);
```

instead of

```
getChoice(Scanner);
```

Incidentally, your `getChoice` method won't compile as shown.  Just return what the scanner returns, which is an `int`, as you declared `getChoice` to return an `int`:

```
public static int getChoice(Scanner n){
    return n.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Why could you not do `int n = in.nextInt()`? Or is it because he didn't declare `n` as an Integer?