# How to return inside a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to have a method that returns the value that is presentend in the while loop. My code represents the reading of a txt file, where I read line by line and my goal is to return everytime it founds a line but is is showing me the same number over and over.

```
public String getInputsTxtFromConsole() {
    String line = "";

    //read inputs file
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

        //read the file line by line
        int lineNum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            lineNum++;

            //Return statement does not work here
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example input file and the result you're trying to get for it? It would make the question clearer.

Comment: The inputs are string like:  96464444; 96464644;94646464 etc

Comment: I just want each number to be returned individually inside the while loop

Comment: The return statement **exits** the function, it won't keep giving you all of the values like yield can in python, create an array of the lines you want and then return the array.

Comment: But I want to return individually and not all at the same time

Comment: Then create the scanner outside the function, pass it as a parameter and have the function return the next value, by recreating the scanner each time you call the function it starts the file again. Or return them all at once and loop over the array

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic Syntax for passing a Scanner object as a Parameter in a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599691/basic-syntax-for-passing-a-scanner-object-as-a-parameter-in-a-function)

Comment: That dont solve my problem

Comment: Change the while to an if-statement and pass the Scanner as a parameter. Each time you call the function is checks there is a line and returns it if there is. Next time you call it it will return the next like and etc.

Comment: Can you show an example @Zachary

Answer (score 0):

As Nick A has said the use of return has, in this context two uses: return the value of a function and exit the function. I you need all the values as the are generated you can, for example,

- Call a method that consume the new value:

  ```
  line = scanner.nextLine();
          lineNum++;
          //Return statement does not work here
          ConsumerMethod(line);
  }
  ```
- Store in a global var like ArrayList, String[],...
- Print it System.out.println(line).
- ...

But you cannot return a value and expect that the function continues working.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, pass the same scanner as a parameter to a method that reads a line and returns the line. You may want to define how it responds once there are no remaining lines.

```
public String getInputsTxtFromConsole(Scanner scanner) {
    try {
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            return scanner.nextLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

I would also recommend using a different class to read from a file. BufferedReader would be a better approach.

```
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (file));
... // in your method
    return in.readLine(); //return null if the end of the stream has been reached
```